# using a library with a release version dll in debug mode (C++/Visual studio)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I am making a C++ shared library in Windows with Visual Studio. I build the library dll's in the release mode. Then, I link that to an application that uses my library. I can use this fine in the release mode. But when I build the application in the debug mode, I get "std::length_error at the memory location ...".

Is this something to do with "_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL"? If so, what should I do? Build the library in all debug levels? My library should not provide any debug symbols

Comment: You can't generally mix debug and release c++ dlls in visual studio

Comment: but then how can people debug when the apps depend on my libraries? Should I provide debug dlls without pdb files?

Comment: yes you should (note that your dlls will also only work with a single version of visual studio (apart from VS 2015-2019 which share a common runtime library)), alternatively avoiding the use of standard library types in your interface and a few other measures will make your dll work with debug and release